# Text whitespaces removed on removing contenteditable property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` and its children `span`. I attached an event with div `click` and `dblclick`.

On `dblclick` i am applying `contenteditable` to `span` and on `click` i am removing

`contenteditable` from `span`. Now my problem is when i enter a large amount of text in

`span` and after that when i `click` over it to remove the `contenteditable` property, all the text

white spaces removed and all text appears in a single line. I created a [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FDYGn/1/). Help me out

please?

**EDIT**

`dblclick` over the div and enter the following text in the fiddle example and then `click` over it

```
(ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
```

Comment: might just be me, but the fiddle doesn't seem to be working at all...

Comment: its working fine , lets try one more time http://jsfiddle.net/FDYGn/1/

Comment: huh, works in chrome but not in FF. But you got an answer already :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `style="Text-wrap:pre;"` to your div